# STM32F415 Problems with I2C

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, i2c, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I am using a STM32F415RGT6 embedded in the 1Bitsy Board. I want to set up the I2C Peripheral in order to read some data from a sensor. I am using the stm32f4 standard peripheral library.

My example code:

```
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE); 

GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioInit;

GPIO_StructInit(&gpioInit);

gpioInit.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;

gpioInit.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7;

gpioInit.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;

gpioInit.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_25MHz; 

GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_I2C1);

GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_I2C1); 

GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpioInit); 

RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE); 

I2C_DeInit(I2C1);

I2C_InitTypeDef I2C_InitStructure;

I2C_StructInit(&I2C_InitStructure);


/* I2C configuration */

I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;

I2C_InitStructure.I2C_ClockSpeed = 100000;

I2C_InitStructure.I2C_DutyCycle = I2C_DutyCycle_2;

I2C_InitStructure.I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0x01;

I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable;

I2C_InitStructure.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit;

I2C_Init(I2C1, &I2C_InitStructure);

I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);


while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1, I2C_FLAG_BUSY));


/* Generate Start, send the address and wait for ACK */

I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE);

while (!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT));

I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2C1, 0xE0, I2C_Direction_Transmitter);


while (!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1,I2C_EVENT_MASTER_TRANSMITTER_MODE_SELECTED));
```

After that I want to write a 0x00, but the code always hangs in the last line, apparently the Master never reads the acknowledge. The I2C status registers always read:

I2C1 -> SR1 = 1024

I2C1 -> SR2 = 3

which means that the Acknowledge Failure bit is always set. If I analyze it using my Saleae I get the following:

[image: STM32F415 Logic Analyzer]

The Slave sends the ACK, but the STM32F415 cannot read it.

The weird thing: If I try the same code on my F407 - Disco (only with clock set to 400khz, but it's the same behaviour on both MCUs regardless of Speed), it works flawlessly:

[image: STM32F407-DISCO Logic Analyzer]

All other peripherals work fine. I already tried several workarounds, but the AF bit is always set, regardless of method. I hope you can help me.

P.S: I have tried with and without additional pullups and the I2C Slave Address is fine, because it works with STM32F0, STM32F4-DISCO and Atmel Mcus.

Best Regards and Thanks in advance!